# Unity rotating object that instatiated from array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

can anyone help me, this is for my final project. i already make script which can spawn object from array storage, then i want to apply some rotation can you guys tell me what shouls i do ?. 
(P.S i included my script below so hope you guys check it out)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class spawn : MonoBehaviour {
    //public string[] objek;
            int buatrandom;
            int jumlahrandom = 16 ;
            int objek1 ;
            int objek2 ;
            int objek3 ;
            public string objname1;
            public string objname2;
            public string objname3;
            public GameObject target1;
            public GameObject target2;
            public GameObject target3;
            public int [] simpannomorobject ;
            public GameObject[] nomorasset;
            public float speed =10f;
        // Use this for initialization
        void Start () {
            simpannomorobject = new int[3]; 
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                buatrandom = Random.Range (0, jumlahrandom);
                simpannomorobject [i] = buatrandom;
        if (i > 0){
            if (i < 3) {
                buatobjek ();
            }
        }
    }

}

void buatobjek (){
    objek1 = simpannomorobject [0];
    objek2 = simpannomorobject [1];
    objek3 = simpannomorobject [2];
    Instantiate (nomorasset [objek1], new Vector3 (0, 0, 3.0f), Quaternion.identity);
    Instantiate (nomorasset [objek2], new Vector3 (4.0f, 0, 0), Quaternion.Euler(0,90,0));
    Instantiate (nomorasset [objek3], new Vector3 (-4.0f, 0, 0), Quaternion.Euler(0,-90,0));
    objname1 = nomorasset [objek1].name;
    objname2 = nomorasset [objek2].name;
    objname3 = nomorasset [objek3].name;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: make rotate animation using script in unity @Hristo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is save them in a variable.

```
GameObject myObject = new GameObject();    
myObject = Instantiate (nomorasset [objek1], new Vector3 (0, 0, 3.0f), Quaternion.identity);
```

and then you can use `myObject` as a reference to the instantiated `GameObject`

Then for the rotating part you could use `Transform.Rotate()`

from [unity scripting API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html):

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        // Rotate the object around its local X axis at 1 degree per second
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime);

        // ...also rotate around the World's Y axis
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
    }
}
```

Then you can just take the transform of the object you just instantiated by using: `myObject.transform.Rotate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime);`

Comment: okay i try it, is the rotation script like this  `myObject.transform.Rotate(Vector3.right *Time.DeltaTime);` @Shogunivar

Comment: Yes, you'll have to put that in the update, so it will trigger every updated frame

Comment: so where i put that `GameObject myObject = new GameObject(); `?, should i put it in start or like public object ? @Shogunivar

Comment: Make a public object like this `public GameObject myObject;`, then just put `myObject = new GameObject();` in the start()

Comment: Thanks dude, you rock, yeaahhhh, thankyou so much @Shogunivar

Answer (score 1):

To referance to an object you Instantiated, instead of:

```
Instantiate (nomorasset [objek1], new Vector3 (0, 0, 3.0f), Quaternion.identity);
```

Just write:

```
GameObject yourObject = Instantiate (nomorasset [objek1], new Vector3 (0, 0, 3.0f), Quaternion.identity);
```

Then, to rotate the object:

```
// Rotate the object around its local X axis at 1 degree per second
yourObject.transform.Rotate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime);
```

For more information about rotating, visit [unity documantation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help i wil try your suggestion too @italy_421